# IOS XMPP how to go next controller with particular username and chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am working on XMPP project. i have successfully completed login process and online ofline rosters. but now i dont know how to go to next view controller with particular user's field and chat with him. here is my try.
**Now what i have to write in UITableview's Delegate Method**

```
friendsviewcontroller.m file // Fetch online and offline rosterlist

  #pragma mark -Tableview datasource method
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
}
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
switch (indexPath.row){
    case 0:
        if(indexPath.section==0)
            return 60.0; // first row is 123pt high
    default:
        return 60.0; // all other rows are 40pt high
 }
 }
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)sender titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];
   if (sectionIndex < [sections count])
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];
    int section = [sectionInfo.name intValue];
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0  : return @"Available";
        case 1  : return @"Away";
        default : return @"Offline";
    }
}
 return @"";}
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex{
NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

if (sectionIndex < [sections count])
 {
     id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = sections[sectionIndex];
     return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
 }
return 0;}
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 if( cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = user.displayName;
            [self configurePhotoForCell:cell user:user];
   // cell.detailTextLabel.text= [self.tblchathistory objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
   }
   #pragma Mark - segue method
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"chathistory"])
    {
   CreateGroupViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
  }
  - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
if (queryElement)
{
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Friend: %@",[[itemElements[i] attributeForName:@"jid"]stringValue]);
        }
}
return NO;
}
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (fetchedResultsController == nil)
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                              cacheName:nil];
    [fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch:= %@", error);
        //NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
    }
}

return fetchedResultsController;
 }

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
[[self tblvwbuddy] reloadData];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the user by following way
While you are showing in one screen that means you have the jid of the user, so take that user's jid and in next controller you can filter the user.
Here is my code to filter the porticular user from `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject` by means of jid. In my case `friendJid` is the jid to be filtered

```
- (XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)fetchTheUser
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext_roster];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jidStr=%@",[self.friendJid lowercaseString]];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[APP_DELEGATE managedObjectContext_roster] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *objTemp = fetchedObjects.count?[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0]:nil;

    return objTemp;
}
```

Hope it will help you.
accept the answer if you find this useful

Comment: so i have to write this code in my next viewcontroller?

Comment: This code is useful to get the particular user, you can use it according to your requirement. I guess as per your requirement you can use it in your next controller

Comment: sorry for noob question. what is filtered jid in my case?

Comment: As you told you have shown all users in one controller, as you are showing it there you have the id for that user (=i.e jid). Suppose you are showing it in the table then in "didselect method" you could have got the index to get the jid.

Comment: yes exactly. you can us my problem. i dont know that what i have to declared in UItable delegate didselect method. so, i can able to move to next view controller with person's username.

Comment: Write this in didselect
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

then in user object you can get stuffs like jid, i suppose.
Try it, i hope it will help you , if so accept the answer and like

Comment: Thanks bro i have successfully implimented as what you said. thanks a lot for help.